# Is there a way to make a derived instance use an existing base instance

Tags: c++, inheritance, allocation, local-functions

For a class hierarchy like:

```
struct base { int i = 1; };
struct derived final : public base
{
    int j = 2;
    void f() { i = 2; }
}; 
// more derivations from base
```

I'd like a way to create an instance of `derived` but using an existing `base` instance.  For example:

```
base b; // b.i == 1
{
derived d;
d.f(); // d.i == 2
}
```

Is there a way to set things up so that after calling `d.f()` the value of `b.i` is 2?  As I've tried to indicate, the lifetime of `derived` is fairly short.

Conceptually, I want to make `base` look like `derived` for a little while, with "look like" meaning access to `d.j`.  When I'm done, I want the changes made to `d.i` to "stick to" `b.i`.  The obvious solution of `base& b` member variable doesn't work because accessing `i` requires different syntax: `b.i` instead of `i`.

Copying the `derived` instance back to `base` when I'm done would work; but that seems rather smelly.

```
{
derived d;
d.f(); // d.i == 2
b = d; // copy, YUCK!
}
```

But I really only want and need one instance of `base`.

---

What's actually going on is that I'm trying to [simulate nested functions](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/058.htm); but I don't want to change the syntax to access either `i` or `j`.

In pseudo-code, I want to do something like:

```
struct s final
{
   int i = 1;
   void f()
   {
      int j = 2;
      auto g = [&]();
   }
   // ... other code ...
   void f::g() { i = 10; j = 20; }
};
```

In other words, the actual code for the "local function" is away from where it's declared.

Comment: *"What's actually going on is that I'm trying to simulate nested functions;"*. lambda might help for that.

Comment: I meant that solution (and question) from your link is from 2002. Currently, there are other solutions.

Comment: Unclear what you can change in the code? is doing `b = d;` (with slicing) solve your issue? ((initial state and) changes done in `d` will be copied to `b`).

Comment: And how do you use `s`?

Comment: How complicated is your real `base`? Could you have references in `d` that refer to the members in your shared base object (e.g., `int &i = b.i;`) without deriving from `base` itself?

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/079669e1a66a2b1b) with lambda, if that help for your inner function.

Comment: Can you post the full pseudo code? (Notice that your pseudo code doesn't use `derived`/`base` at all :/, and in you first snippet, `d` is unrelated to `b`).

Comment: You cannot define something at function scope outside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to share the same member variable of object `b` with a **different** object `d` that serves as a decorator/view of `b`, because different objects have different sets of values for member variables.

If `derived` is derived from `base`, then the `base`-object is part of every `derived`-object and you cannot destroy the `derived`-object without destroying the intrinsic `base`-object as well.

If `derived` is not derived from `base`, then you cannot replace variables that expect a `base`-object with an object of type `derived` in your code; any `xxx.i` in your code will either work for `xxx` being an object of type `base` or for `xxx` being an object of type `derived`, but not for both. So applying a common code containing `xxx.i` to objects of `derived` and objects of `base` will not work (unless you have a macro like `#define impl_f(b) { (b).i = 2; }`, but I don't thing that you think of reusable code in form of makros).

A way I could think of is a derived class that enforces to be initialized with a `base`-object and copies back the (changed) values to this base-object once `derived` is destroyed:

```
struct base {
    int i = 1;
    base() { }
    base(base &_b) { i = _b.i; }
};

struct derived_base : public base
{
    derived_base(base &_b) : base(_b), b(_b)  {  }
    ~derived_base() { b = *this; }
    
private:

    base &b;
};

struct derived1 final : public derived_base
{
    int j = 2;
    
    derived1(base &_b) : derived_base(_b) { }
    
    void f() { i = 2; }
};



int main() {

base b; // b.i == 1
cout << "b member i (should be 1):" << b.i << std::endl;

{
    derived1 d(b);
    cout << "initially, d member i should be the value of b.i, i.e. 1:" << d.i << std::endl;
    d.f(); // d.i == 2
    cout << "after f(), d member i (should be 2):" << d.i << std::endl;
}

cout << "lifetime of d ended; b has overtaken the values from d" << std::endl;
cout << "b member i (should now be 2, too):" << b.i << std::endl;

}
```